# How to change pandas dataframe plot from vertical to horizontal and add line spacing for the axis labels?

Tags: python, pandas

I plotted a dataframe using the following command

```
df['col1'].value_counts().plot.bar(orientation='vertical')
```

[image]

The output is shown as above. I would like to change two things:

1. swap the x and y axis so i can read the current x axis text from left to right (NOTE the current x axis labels contains long text and it is hard to read it vertically. Picture is truncated at the bottom for simplicity of this post)
2. add line spacing between the labels for the current x axis so it helps reading (will be on the y axis if step 1 is done). If increasing the size of the plot is needed, please suggest how to do so.

I have tried a few things but none of them have any visible effects. e.g.,

```
plt.xticks(linespacing=1.5)
np.linspace(-1, 1, 10000)
```

Comment: You can plot horizontally directly:  `x.plot(kind='barh')`. Not sure changing the space between labels will help with so many points.

Comment: @fsl does increasing the size of the chart helps? Actually there ain't that many labels, the ones showin the in pictures are not really overlapping with each other. it is only about 50ish labels

Comment: You might play around with the font size and see if it fits, i.e. `plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6})` (before plotting).

Comment: @fsl  hmm..Increasing char size actually helps. When plotting barh chart, how can i make all the bar align to the left side? right now it is centered aligned

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the default is to the left. Are you passing any arguments to your plot call?

Comment: Remove the `orientation='vertical'`.

Comment: Thank you @Emma!

Comment: @fsl, I increase the size of the plot using     `plt.figure(figsize=(5, 20))` which gives enough room for the labels to expand. If you like to write an answer with this and your suggestion plus emma's suggestions. I am happy to take it! Either way, thank you!

Comment: @fsl, btw the font size did not take any effect...

Comment: Make sure you set the font size before calling `plot`. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot horizontally directly. Also, consider setting a different font size in advance, e.g.:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6})  # Arbitrary
df['col1'].value_counts().plot(kind="barh", figsize=(5, 20))
```